# What are the available options (March 2021) for bridging tokens across the chains?

Tags: contract-deployment, gas-price, cross-chain, xdai

#### Actual problem in mind

**I would like to release a token for the [Island DAO](https://islanddao.org/).**

I'm worried that ETH gas prices are prohibitively expensive - if I use ETH, the smaller guys will not come.

But ETH is the chain with the most amount of capital - if I don't use ETH, the bigger guys will not come.

[image]

**That is why I would like to have best of both worlds from the ground up**

1. Be available on Ethereum mainnet
2. Be available on other, much more affordable chain

#### Projects in the space

- Binance bridge: https://www.binance.org/en/bridge
- AnySwap bridge: https://anyswap.exchange/bridge
- XDAI omni bridge: https://omni.xdaichain.com/
- ETH / BSC / Terra shuttle: https://github.com/terra-project/shuttle
- UPDATE. Yet another bridge: https://burgerswap.org/

#### Additional consideration: Oracles and other parts of DeFi ecosystem?

That is on the ETH chain only, BSC does not have native oracles deployed to the mainnet.

Answer (score 1):

[Arbitrum](https://offchainlabs.com/) is a layer 2 solution that uses Rollups. (Caveat: It's not yet live on main net.)

There's a bridge, here: https://bridge.offchainlabs.com/

Chainlink oracles are (or will be) [natively supported](https://twitter.com/chainlink/status/1228462083328618496?lang=en).

Various DeFi protocols have already been ported across (e.g. [Uniswap](https://swap.arbitrum.io/#/swap), [Aave](https://aarbe.arbitrum.io/)).

(I'm not affiliated with them, but have looked into using their platform.)

Answer (score 1):

Fresh off the press via Daily Ape: https://twitter.com/AndreCronjeTech/status/1373197364656242690

https://andrecronje.medium.com/deploying-your-own-cross-chain-token-101-240420efd0d9

I would need to copy-paste the entire article, it's very detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Uniswap and MakerDAO has announced their official support for [Optimism](https://optimism.io/) so network effect wise there is hard to beat that.